# how to pass array of javascript objects to php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a bunch of values that need to be passed to the server, and I can't seem to get the basic functions like JSON decode to work. Something is off here, I'll appreciate someone to look at it

I have a dynamically generated table with editable values that I grab when user clicks Add button, push it into an array and send it off to the server with ajax call. Here's sample data sent over that I copied from console.log(data); line.

```
var data = params + "&Details="+JSON.stringify(Details);
console.log(data);     // &Id[]=1566&aId[]=1567&Details=[["1566","First File","sdf.pdf","general","file","",""],["1567","2nd file","test.png","image","file","",""]] 

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: editUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function() { console.log('success'); }
    error: function() { console.log('error'); }
});
```

On the server side I get the data but I can't parse it into usable format

```
$ids = ($_POST['Id']);    // this is a valid array
$details = ($_POST['Details']);     // [[ 1566 , First File ,  , general , file ,  ,  ],[ 1567 , 2nd file ,  , image , file ,  ,  ]]
$details = json_decode($details);   // getting JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR error and null is returned
```

any idea what's wrong in here?

Comment: You should always use `encodeURIComponent` when adding complex parameters to a URL. Or give an object to jQuery, and it will do the encoding automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the JSON properly:

```
var data = params + "&Details="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(Details));
```

However, it would be better, IMHO, to make `data` an object rather than a string.

```
var data = {
    Id: [ 1566, 1567],
    Details: JSON.stringify(Details)
};
```

You'll need to change how you create `params` so it produces an object as well. You can then use `$.extend()` to merge them:

```
var data = $.extend({}, params, { Details: JSON.stringify(Details) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax parameter missing a `comma` after success function, and try to define success function callback from server as data and then use json_encode for your array data in php server.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: editUrl,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: data,
   success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
   error: function() { console.log('error'); }
});
```

Comment: That must be a copying error, because the Javascript wouldn't even run without that comma.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are building out params variable or why. But if it's just to send via ajax you don't have to.  The data parameter of ajax will do this for you.  Give it an object with your name/value pairs that you want to send.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: editUrl,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 
    Id: [2566],
    aId: [1567],
    Details: Details,
    Other: 'Hi',
    AnotherId: 1234
  }
  success: function() { console.log('success'); }
  error: function() { console.log('error'); }
});
```

On the server take a look at all the $_POST variable to get an idea of what was sent and the format

```
<?php
  echo '<pre>'
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

try `json_decode(stripslashes($details))`

Comment: This would only be needed if his configuration has `magic_quote_gpc` enabled.

Comment: why -1 ? you shell provide a comment

Comment: And what if he has that enabled? How do you know?

Comment: I hope he doesn't. It's an obsolete feature that has been removed in recent versions. It would be better to disable it than to use this workaround.